# Google map in avada theme not displaying on any page

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am using Avada theme version 4.0.3. My problem is that I'm inserting a Map on the contact page using theme options with all the options entered correctly. But the map is not visible on front-end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the current `Avada` version you are using. Either update your theme or follow the steps mentioned below:

- Google has change its policy of using google map in your website.
- You need to patch your avada theme from `AVADA` menu -> `Support`
- You can find `AVADA PATCHER` apply all patch
- Go to your `theme-options` and you will find new option google api key
- Get your `API key` from google console and place it in your theme option.

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For your Google Maps to display on your page, you now need to use the Google Maps JavaScript API key. To generate a new API key, please click the button below for Google’s ‘Get A Key/Authentication’ article. Please read it carefully as there are different methods for Standard API users and Premium Plan users.

[Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?utm_source=geoblog&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=2016-geo-na-website-gmedia-blogs-us-blogPost&utm_content=TBC%3Cbr%20/%3E)

**Step 1** – If you’re on Avada version 4.0.3, or update to the latest available Avada version.

**Step 2** – Go to the Avada > Theme Options > Contact Form > Google Map panel.

**Step 3** – Locate the ‘Google Maps API Key’ option and enter your generated API key.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not come alright with the above mentioned, you can always do it manually:

Simply add the API key to the adava script class
/themes/Avada/includes/class-avada-scripts.php

```
    $map_api = 'http' . ( ( is_ssl() ) ? 's' : '' ) . '://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBL2dPCqgUTzrUMlfgUt30kGQLt6ZKKu_E&language=' . substr( get_locale(), 0, 2 );
```

Comment: I tried this solution but nothing changes on page load. I cannot update this theme too. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

To get Google Maps working you have to create a Account:

```
New Users: Before you can start using the Google Maps Platform APIs and SDKs, you must sign up and create a billing account. To learn more, see Get Started with Google Maps Platform.
```

[Check](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)